# Is my Port 3838 Open based on this netstat -tulpn?

Tags: linux, networking, centos, centos-6

I am trying to host a Shiny R Web Server on a CentOS Virtual Machine.  I am troubleshooting some networking issues, but I want to confirm that the port is open.

I have a Static IP address for this Virtual Machine, but when I navigate to Static_IP_Address:3838/ , the connection times out.  So, is Port 3838 open?

[image]

**Update:**
Here is the outcome of `nmap`:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: is virtual machine network device bridged ? is VM (with shiny server) pingable from outside ?

Comment: The VM network is bridged.  I can ping the VM's static IP address.  How do I ping the VM's static IP address with the shiny server?

Comment: Did you run the `nmap` from the machine in question or another one?  If you ran it locally you might not actually get blocked by the firewall, you should try running it from another machine

Comment: I ran nmap from the host machine.  Let me run it from another machine.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Marius.  Just two more questions... Could there possibly be an issue with how the static IP Address was created by my IT team?  Why doesn't 10.18.81.251 show up in the IPv4 Route Table?

Answer (score 1):

The above cannot tell you whether the port is open, only whether there is anything listening on that port. And there is, as you can see from the first line, which  laso identifies the program listening as `shiny-server`, as per your desire.

The command to see whether the firewall is guarding the port is `nmap`.For instance,

```
# nmap -p80 192.168.73.96

  Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-11-30 15:50 CET
  Nmap scan report for d2.my.lan (192.168.73.96)
  Host is up (0.00052s latency).
  PORT   STATE  SERVICE
  80/tcp closed http
  MAC Address: 08:00:27:18:F9:44 (Cadmus Computer Systems)

  Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.51 seconds
```

In your case substitute `3838` in the command to `80`. `Closed` means there is no program listening on it, while you are hoping to find `open`. There are [several other possibilities](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html).

Most likely, you are having a routing problem. You should look at your routing table, and see whether it can reach your VM.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity purposes, I wanted to post an answer to how I finally got my Shiny Server up and running.

1. I disabled `iptables`:

/etc/init.d/iptables save

/etc/init.d/iptables stop

chkconfig iptables off

2. I changed /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf to listen on Port 8080 **instead** of Port 3838.  On Port 3838, I could not access the web application from any other computer on the network.  But from Port 8080, I could.

Comment: Good! Like I said: not a routing problem...

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue, but for me the solution was with the internal firewall of Centos 7, so I enabled it, and restart:

```
#firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-port=3838/tcp
#firewall-cmd --reload
```

found the answer on the centos forum working with different ports, source: https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=57945